# how to remove duplicates in the table generated in sql using python

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

I run two queries in python (that would generate two different data sets but has the same title). I combined them into one data set using python and it looks something like this: (however this actual data set is not showing anywhere, I just use table_a + table_b and combined them into one)

```
date      symbol    data
10/9/2018   a       0.1
10/9/2018   b       0.2
10/9/2018   c       0.3
10/9/2018   a       0.1
10/9/2018   a       0.1
```

If i want to remove the duplicates symbol and produce output like:

```
date      symbol    data
10/9/2018   a       0.1
10/9/2018   b       0.2
10/9/2018   c       0.3
```

how should I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `select distinct`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could have found this with a search for 'SQL remove duplicates' http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Are you using pandas dataframe?as you mentioned table,tagged sql but want to remove using python. It is confusing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows. You don't post your SQL but it should look like:

```
select distinct date, symbol, data from my_table
```

Please note that `DISTINCT` applies to the full row, not the first column only.

Comment: Hi, the dates are the same though, but I only want to select distinct symbol (does not matter if they have the same date). How can the distinct function tell that which one I am selecting from?

Comment: and by the way I want to remove the duplicates through python, not sql.